# Find the volume of the body bounded by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the volume of the body bounded by $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 4$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

This is the last subject in our syllabus and I am afraid that my professor had not any time to teach it before the end of the semester, and left us wondering in the land of calculating body volumes in $3D$. I know this can be done by double integral, but I would be happy if someone showed me direction into solving such questions.

Comment: Not yet, will try again in a few minutes.

Comment: Got the answer $11.43$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volume can be found as

> $$V=\int\int\int dV =  \int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}}dzdydx .$$

Or just, you can use the double integral as

> $$ V = \int\int (z_2-z_1)dA, $$

where $z_1=z_1(x,y)$ and $z_2=z_2(x,y)$ and $dA=dydx$. In your case

$$ z_1= -\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2},\quad z_2= \sqrt{4-x^2-y^2} .$$

Here is a plot, so you can see what's going on

[image]

Comment: I was looking more for a thorough explanation of this, of how to even begin thinking about it. I am not only looking to solving it, I also want to understand!

Comment: @TheNotMe: Just note that, we want to find the volume of the region which is bounded by a sphere and cylinder of radius one. Plot the region to see it. Then take a strip parallel to the z-axix which is within the cylinder and bounded from below and above by the sphere and this how I found the limits for $z$. For the limits of $x$ and $y$, you can see that our region in the $xy$-plane is a circle of radius one. The point is have you used double integrals to find areas? If so, then the volue should not be hard.

Comment: You mean $z_1 = - \sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}$ and $z_2 =  \sqrt{4 - x^2 - y^2}$, right?

Comment: And another question, if we do the second integral, then what is the use of the second equation ($x^2 + y^2 = 1$)?

Comment: @TheNotMe: The use of the second equation is that it gives you the region in the $xy$-plane to find the limits of integration for $x$ and $y$ which is in this case is a circle.

Comment: @TheNotMe: Yes, you are correct. I mean $z_1=-\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$ and $z_2=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$.

Comment: So what is the full integral we get using the 2nd equation? ($z2 - z1$)

Comment: (+1) You are a real teacher Dr.Mhenni. @MhenniBenghorbal

Comment: I got the answer $~11.43$. Did you get the same?

Comment: @TheNotMe: It is 11.74472927. Mhenni's and mine are the same value.

Comment: Yes I didn't calculate it approxiametly.

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you very much for the comment. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to find the proper volume. Just think about $z\ge0$ and then double the volume to find the whole volume. In fact, being symmetric is essential point in this case. So we can establish the following integrals: $$V_0=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{r=0}^{r=1}\int_{z=0}^{z=\sqrt{4-r^2}}r dr d\theta dz$$ via Cylindrical coordinates and so finally have $V_{\text{Whole}}=2V_0$. The below plot shows $V_0$.

[image]

Comment: But how do we begin of thinking about it? I mean, should I draw it on a $2D$ plane? should I put $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ for the second equation?

Comment: @TheNotMe: Yes, we have to draw a 2D plot for the are the whole volume is established on. That is the unit circle. In it, we have $r=0..1$ and $\theta=0..2\pi$.

Comment: Nice graphics always help!